# Performance. How do I get grid devices to sleep when not in use?

Tags: bitwig

I would like my grid items to sleep when there is neither audio nor note-events entering them.  I have a drum machine with a bunch of FX grids.  Here is a photo of the cpu usage when my grid devices are enabled vs disabled.  None of them are creating any audio, or receiving any audio.  None of them are receiving note events.  This is a fully silent, nothing running project.

Is there a way to make grid devices stop hogging cpu they don't need?  I would like for them to stop sending audio down the line once their envelopes are closed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The grid uses a voice system to determine whether grid modules are in use. Using one of the mono voice modes will mean that the modules are always activate even when no note input is being received.

The best way to prevent this is to use a voice mode with multiple voices. When using polyphony (non-mono voices) the grid will not consume any CPU power if there is no note input. You can change polyphony modes from the inspector panel when you have one of the grids selected - the parameter is called 'voices', and there are three states true mono, digi mono and polyphony (where a number is shown). If voices show as 'mono' you can click and drag on it to set voices to a number.

The other piece of the puzzle with the polyphony grid mode is how bitwig knows to keep the voice active. There are a few different modules that determine if the voice is kept active:

- ADSR or AR envelopes can be used to keep the voice alive after release for time period equal to the release parameter
- The Audio Out I/O module can be used to keep the voice alive if there is audio output happening above a threshold
- Gate In also keeps voices alive but just for the length of the incoming gate

For each of these you'll need to enable the 'keep voice alive' setting in the inspector panel for the module.

Comment: Thank you Pike!  I had been digging around after putting in this question and ended up trying all of the above.  Even with all the changes, the no-input grids are still consuming a lot of resources.  Marginally less at least.  I think I might have to actually automate turning them on and off to get them to where they should be.  Do you happen to know if the BItwig team does zero input optimization?  It seems strange that device chains don't inherently skip by each node if it's known zero in will equal zero out.

Comment: There is a new update available which has some grid performance updates - [5.0.5 Release notes](https://downloads.bitwig.com/5.0.5/Release-Notes-5.0.5.html).

If you have an example where performance is poor in a basic case you can share the preset with Bitwig support at support@bitwig.com. In my experience they are very quick to respond to newly introduced issues.